# How do I configure the Image Properties dialog box in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

My current Image Properties dialog box only has the `Image Info` and `Link` tabs available. I want to change this dialog box so that:

1. I want to remove the Width, Height, Border, HSpace, VSpace, Alignment, and Preview elements from the `Image Info` screen
2. I want to remove the `Link` tab
3. I want to enable the `Upload` tab so that users can choose an image file that resides on their local computer

I've been doing lots of searches but can't understand how to do the above at all. Any pointers please? I am using CKEditor 4.4.6 Standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, here's the code on how handle the *Image dialog*:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'image') {
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        infoTab.remove( 'txtBorder' ); //Remove Element Border From Tab Info
        infoTab.remove( 'txtHSpace' ); //Remove Element Horizontal Space From Tab Info
        infoTab.remove( 'txtVSpace' ); //Remove Element Vertical Space From Tab Info
        infoTab.remove( 'txtWidth' ); //Remove Element Width From Tab Info
        infoTab.remove( 'txtHeight' ); //Remove Element Height From Tab Info

        //Remove tab Link
        dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Link' );
    }
});
```

For point 3, the default CKEditor doesn't contain Image Browsing Facility... And this mean that the upload and browse button will not appear...

There is 3 options here, and you can see my comment on this page: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604522/upload-and-browse-server-button-not-visible-in-ckeditor/28552206#28552206)  on how you can do this.

Comment: I'm using ckeditor 4.x I tried removing the link tab using above code but it doesn't work. I'm getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null.

Comment: @Moe i didn't get **definition** in **ev.data** object

Comment: 4 years later this was a great answer.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The following resources might be helpful:

- The [Dialog Windows](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_dialog_windows) HOWTO section in CKEditor developer documentation.
- The [Using CKEditor Dialog API](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/dialog/dialog.html) sample (it is also available in your local CKEditor package) -- check its source code for how the changes are done.
- The [Developer Tools](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/devtools.html) plugin which shows you the names and IDs of all CKEditor dialog window elements.

Comment: I've looked at that documentation but I'm still quite confused. I just want to add the ability for a user to select an image file on their local machine to include in their textarea, rather than a URL that points to an image file hosted elsewhere. Can you please suggest how to do that?