# Disable width and height fields from image properties windows

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Disable width and height fields from image properties I am using ckeditor 4

CKEDITOR.replace('<%=txtCkEditor.ClientID %>', {allowedContent:'img[!src,alt];'});

By using above method it shows only image properties with width and height hidden and rest of the controls also get visible false. Kindly suggest me a solution for disabling the width and height fields from image properties windows.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question. It seems you want to hide the fields that allow input of height and width. Your initial solution doesn't seem to affect the dialog box, but what content gets saved. These are very different kinds of solutions. My answer assumes you're seeking to alter the image properties dialog box fields.

Based on [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356098/how-do-i-configure-the-image-properties-dialog-box-in-ckeditor), I recommend adding the following configuration:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    var editor = ev.editor;
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'image') {
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        infoTab.remove( 'txtWidth' ); // Remove width element from Info tab
        infoTab.remove( 'txtHeight' ); // Remove height element from Info tab
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @ANTONYVIMAL, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.